# Calling Angular2 service in a loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service written that sends some data to an API request. However, i need to call it multiple times depending on how many checkboxes a user clicked. What is the best way to do this? I was looking into Observables `forkJoin` method but am not sure how to implement it.

Here is how i currently call the service (without loop):

```
this.myService.update(id, data).subscribe(
    data => { 
        console.log('Data: ', data);
    },
    error => { console.log('Error: ', error }
);
```

Comment: Please add your html

Comment: @PatrickJane There is no HTML for this scenario. Just a bunch of `ids` in an array that i need to loop over and call this service method in it.

Comment: Where is the checkboxes

Comment: They are part of another component. I just get the checked ids passed to me in an array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay i found a way to do it:

```
let observables = new Array();

for( let id of ids ) {
    observables.push(this.myService.update(id, data));
}

Observable.forkJoin(observables).subscribe(
    res => console.log(res),
    error => console.log('Error: ', error)
);
```

Basically i made an array of the service i needed to execute in parallel and then passed it to `forkJoin`. When all the observables are complete, the response is passed into the `res` argument of the subscribe method.